# Shelljs -- how do I represent the tmux base command "Ctrl-B" as a command?

Tags: shelljs

I'm trying to use `shelljs` to write a script that'll help load up my local env at once while setting up my `tmux panes/windows`... but I don't know how to represent the `Ctrl` button in the command.

Help? :-|

example of what I thought would work:
`shell.exec('Control+b z');`

Answer (score 0):

Solution with keyboard shortcuts is probably not possible (not to my knowledge).

But that's the part where tmux command takes part.

For example in my setup I want to open two side panels along with main pane.

I'm using following with Guake terminal:

```js
// Rename tab to current path
shell.exec(`guake --rename-current-tab=${path} &`);
// Open new horizontal pane
shell.exec('tmux split-window -h');
// Open new vertical pane under pane that was created above
shell.exec('tmux split-window -v');
```

Here you can find a cheatsheet for tmux commands: https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058

Comment: oh nice. I *think* that could work. Do you have any suggestions on how I can inject commands into each respective window? I guess I'd have to look at the other tmux commands.

Comment: I set up such thing only with basic .sh script (haven't tried to do it with shelljs yet).
`tmux split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}" \; send-keys "npm run build" Enter &`
But it should work with shelljs